# Escape parentheses in nested batch for loop?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, command-prompt

I have a folder which contains an unknown number of .txt files named as such:

```
todo.txt
todo (1).txt
todo (2).txt
todo (3).txt
```

I'm running this command to iterate through the files and print the text on each line within the files: `for /r %f in (test\*.txt) do (for /f %p in (%f) do echo %p)`

/r returns the file names correctly and /f will output each line of text in todo.txt but when it hits `todo (1).txt` it performs the command `for /f %p in (C:\test\todo (1).txt) do echo %p` and errors out saying `The system cannot find the file C:\test\todo.`

How do you escape parentheses in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `usebackq` option to allow you to double-quote the filename

```
for /r %f in (test\*.txt) do (for /f "usebackq" %p in ("%f") do echo %p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Surround the file name between quotes:

```
"C:\test\todo (1).txt"
```

Actually the problem is the white spaces, not the parenthesis.

Comment: `for /r %f in (test\*.txt) do (for /f %p in ("%f") do echo %p)`? When I do that, it echo's the path\file and not the contents of the text files. It also still errors with todo (1).txt, echo'ing `C:\test\todo`